# How to use boost libraries on Android

Tags: android, qt, boost

I am working on android application with Qt. How can i use boost libraries for devoloping android application? I have boost library for msvc, can i use for android?HOw to integrate boost library to Qt?

Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem. If anyone faces this problem, i am listing solution  below

Step 1: Go to this site https://github.com/PurpleI2P/Boost-for-Android-Prebuilt/branches

Step2: Download the prebuilt library that want to download.

Step3: Go to Qt and add library, Project->Add library-> external library

Step4: Include library in your source code(i.e. include<boost\chrono.hpp>)

It doesn't need editing pro file manually, Step3 will make automatically!

Answer (score 0):

You need to build boost for android (armv7, armv8, x86 and x64). Then link boost to your project in the pro file or in the cmake files and bundle boost in the apk (from the pro file).
A build for msvc cannot be compatible with Android.